# Validating data in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, validation

I'm working on a project that has code and data parts. Data part is actually a lot of dictionary like txt files. Dictionary is maintained by humans, manually adding new lines using text editors. Manual work can lead to some of the following errors: illegal format, typos, etc...

In order to prevent run time error in production (for example: due to bad dictionary line format), I want to validate dictionary data during the build. So my question is: is it a good practice to validate data during the build, in a unit test? If not, what would be the best solution?

Note: we have regular test we run before pushing the code to production, but preventing project to build would be most desirable solution.

Thanks.

Comment: This is seems not to be unit-testing.

Comment: I think that as well, but if I have to validate data during the build, what would you suggest. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests should test modular blocks of code in a reproducible way using predefined and unchanging data.

If you want to validate external data files it should be done within the program or with an additional tool.

Comment: we already do that, both validating data within program and using additional tool. Validating data in program is a bit slow, so it would be desirable doing it before running the program. If I have to do it during the build what would you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Like with checked and unchecked exceptions there's not really much a program designed to process data can do about the validity of data outwith it's control.  
 If you are using a build manager like ANT you could simply add an ant task that runs the external tool either before build or before distribution as required.

Comment: Thanks Ross. I'm using maven, but I guess there's an option in maven as well.

Comment: It's easy enough to combine the two :)